# VBA Add-in Vlookup ThisWorkbook.Range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I am attempting to create an add-in with a VLOOKUP from a range on the add-in sheet. This is too long to do with case (3000+ lines) and I don't want to have to have the user store this file.

```
Function WSort(strng)
Dim DivR, wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet


    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("HEA")
    strng = Left(strng, 5)

    WSort = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RetStr, ws1.Range("C2:D4000"), 2, False)
End Function
```

I have tried writing this several ways and I keep running into the issue that I cant reliably reference the HEA Tab. I have tried using Sheet3 and Sheets(4).

Comment: Are you getting an error with this code?  What is the error and on which line?  Note if the lookup fails to make a match, you'll get a run-time error, so you'll need to handle that case.

Comment: The I am just getting #value. If I convert this to just Sheet4.Range("C:D") it works fine. As I understand, you have to use ThisWorkbook for add-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Function WSort(strng)
    Dim m
    m = Application.VLookup(strng, _
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HEA").Range("C2:D4000"), 2, False)
    WSort = IIf(IsError(m), "NoMatch", m)
End Function
```

If you still get an error, try calling the function from VBA so you can debug.

Answer (score 0):

When I was saved it as Add-in for testing, it changed ThisWorkbook to ThisWorkbook1. Updated the line and everything worked perfectly!